# Render item from an array after a fixed interval in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to array items on after another. But it is only displaying the last element of the array.

Expected output is displaying "a" after 2 seconds "b" and so on.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      role: ["a","b","c"],
      display: "",
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    for (let i of this.state.role) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ display: i})
      }, 2000)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h3>{this.state.display}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: what error or problem are you facing ? and what are you expecting after 4 seconds have passed should it show `a` again ?

Comment: You have incorrectly closed the brackets in `componentDidMount`, especially where you have invoked the `setState` and `setTimeout`.

Comment: Even though I see why you would like to use setState (as it causes a re render), I think it's unnecessary to store to state a duplicate array just for semantic purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a loop to create a timeout on componentDidMount. In such a case what would happen is that the loop will complete immedialtely creating 3 timers which resolve at nearly the same 2sec interval from the start and setState then batches all the three state update calls resulting in only the last one to be displayed.

In order to solve this you can make use of `setInterval` like below

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      role: ["a","b","c"],
      display: "",
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var index = 0;
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ display: this.state.role[index]});
      index  = (index + 1)%(this.state.role.length);
    }, 2000)
  }

  componentWillUnmounnt() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <h3>{this.state.display}</h3>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: If you do not want to repeat the order of roles again and again on display, you can clear the interval once the size of the array is reached

Comment: If you want timer for 1 cycle, you can use `setTimeout` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use way multiple the `index` to create 3 different timeouts.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      role: ["a","b","c"],
      display: "",
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.role.forEach((item, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ display: item})
      }, 2000*(index+1))
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h3>{this.state.display}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `for (x of y)` runs directly and all three `setTimeouts` created almost at once, then you see the result only of the last one cause they have 1-2 ms difference between them.
I used `for (x in y)`instead to have the item index. Then I am using the item index to calculate its timeout based on its index.
This is my approach:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {    super(props);
    this.state = {
      role: ["a", "b", "c"],
      display: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    for (let i in this.state.role) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          display: this.state.role[i],
        });
      }, 2000 * i);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>{this.state.display}</h3>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```